# Where is my num_rows failing?

Tags: mysqli, mysql-num-rows

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');
$link->query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS users');
$link->Select_db('users');

$sql='SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '.$useremail.' AND username = '.$username;
$results = $link->query($sql);
$numrows = $results->num_rows;

if ($numrows == 1) {
    #update user information
} else {
    #failed to update
}
?>
```

It only works part of the time, and i'm not able to nail down an error from it one way or the other.  I can confirm that the error pops up on the $numrows=$results->num_rows; line, but as for why, i'm lost.  Occasionally it will work as intended, so any and all advice on what i can do to fix it, or at least helping me understand it better is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Double Quotation for query and varchar/string pass with single quotation

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".$useremail."' AND username = '".$username."'";
$results = $link->query($sql);
$numrows = $results->num_rows();
```

Comment: That was tested as well, and passes without any apparent issue.  In the original code, we did use '".$var... etc.  The issue is with num_rows failing.  Placing (as is in your example) a open/close parenthesis after it fires a fatal error 115.  While i do appreciate the input, your suggestion didn't improve the situation with num_rows, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your call to `num_rows` generated an error is that your query had an error, and `query()` returned **false** instead of a valid result resource. Because it's a fatal error to try to call a method on a false value, you should always check the return value of `query()` before using it. Example:

```
if (!($result = $link->query($sql))) {
    die($link->error);
}
```

Problems with your query:

- You create a database named `users` and make that the default database, then you run a SELECT query from a *table* named `users`. There would be no tables in a database you have just created. In SQL, we use SELECT against tables, not databases (these are two different things, analogous to files contained in a directory on a filesystem).
- You don't quote the string arguments in your SQL statement.  For example, this SQL would be an error:

  ```
  SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = bill@example.com AND username = bill
  ```

  It should be this instead:

  ```
  SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'bill@example.com' AND username = 'bill'
  ```

  I know the quotes get confusing, because you have PHP string quotes and then SQL string quotes, but here are several ways of accomplishing it:

  ```
  $sql='SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = \''.$useremail.'\' AND username = \''.$username.'\'';
  $sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".$useremail."' AND username = '".$username."'";
  $sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$useremail}' AND username = '{$username}'";
  ```
- I'm not sure if you have protected your PHP variables appropriately. You must *never* interpolate PHP variables into SQL strings unless you have escaped the content of the variables.

  ```
  $useremail_esc = $link->real_escape_string($useremail);
  $username_esc = $link->real_escape_string($username);
  $sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$useremail_esc}' AND username = '{$username_esc}'";
  ```
- But it would be better to use *prepared statements* with parameter placeholders. This is easier to use than escaping variables, and it's more reliable. Here's an example:

  ```
  $sql="SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? AND username = ?";
  $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $useremail, $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  ```

  Notice that you don't use escaping when you use parameters, and you don't put SQL quotes around the `?` placeholders.

Comment: From there, I just use $result->num_rows?  (sorry about the quotations, i was typing this up from memory, and some details tend to slip.  The database in question was fully fleshed out, and the entries were there, but no matter what it returned a 0.)

Comment: Sorry, i'm still having some trouble with this. the $stmt->get_resut() returned an error as an undefined function.

Comment: The `get_result()` function is available only if you have mysqlnd, which should be enabled by default in PHP 5.4.0 and later. See http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php